# IEEE LaTeX style: grouping references together

Tags: bibliographies, citing, ieee-style

I'm citing 3 articles together in my thesis and latex displays it as [1; 2; 3], But I want it as [1-3] How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

My M. W. E. and sample bib is attached below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{article1,article2,article3}
\bibliography{zoteroexport.bib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{document}

@article{soames_detecting_2019,
    title = {Detecting {Cycles} in {GraphQL} {Schemas}},
    author = {Soames, Kieron and Lind, Jonas},
    year = {2019},
    keywords = {cycle detection}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I was able to find the solution from there since I was using natbib \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}, this worked for me.

Comment: Ok, good that you solved it. Let's close this question as a real duplicate then.

Comment: @Mensch No, But the question provided by Marijn did answer my question.